# varchar not recognized as a valid datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server-ce

This is my code:

[image]

As you can see **varchar** is not recognized as a Data-Type and it gives an error when executed.

Does anyone know why?

Comment: Please put your code in your message, not as static images that cannot be copied/pasted for testing. Also, "salary" should never be a float.

Answer (score 1):

looks like you are using sql server CE, if so you need to use `nvarchar`

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine, but you are missing a "," in the second table. See below.

CREATE TABLE Employee170340
(
eno Integer,
ename varchar(20),
job varchar(20),
dno Integer,
salary float
constraint Employee_170340 PRIMARY KEY (eno)
)

CREATE TABLE Family170340
(
eno Integer,
name varchar(15),
relationship varchar(20),
constraint Family_170340 primary key (eno, name)
,constraint Family_870 foreign key (eno) references Employee170340 (eno)
)